# Deployed digitalocean app isn't reading environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, deployment, environment-variables, digital-ocean

I have deployed an app to digitalocean using the [Ruby on Rails image](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/ruby-on-rails). It is set up by default with a user called `rails`. My `rails.service` file looks like:

```
[Unit] 
Description=OneMathsExamQuestions 
Requires=network.target 

[Service] 
Type=simple 
User=rails 
Group=rails 
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/one_maths_exam_questions/ 
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma' 
TimeoutSec=30s 
RestartSec=30s 
Restart=always 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I need to use some environment variables in my application. So I have added some lines to my `/home/rails/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc` files (I suspect only the first one should be necessary but neither seems to work):

```
export A="val1"
export B="val2"
...
```

Now: if I call `echo $A` in a terminal I get the expected output. If I go into the Rails console and do `ENV["A"]` I get the expected output. But my app does not seem to behave correctly (the desired behaviour is connecting to Amazon S3; the exact error is not important).

If I go into my controller and explicitly log the env vars with `Rails.logger.debug ENV` I just get `ENV`, and `Rails.logger.debug ENV["A"]` returns empty string (I guess `nil`). Similarly if I try to do `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` which should definitely work, I get the same. But `Rails.env` returns `"development"`, as expected.

Moreover, if I explicitly write

```
ENV["A"] = "val1"
ENV["B"] = "val2"
...
```

in my `config/application.rb`, the app works correctly. But this is obviously not a permanent solution, since I can't commit this to version control.

I'm not using the `figaro` gem, which I think a lot of places are suggesting, but I don't see why I should have to since it works just fine on my local machine.

Comment: Do you load the `rbenv` in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: @AHT If I understand you correctly, I think they use `rvm` rather than `rbenv`. There is a line in `.bashrc` which adds `$HOME/.rvm/bin` to the `$PATH`, but I think that's it.

Comment: At one point I tried to change `'bundle exec puma'` to `source /home/rails/.bashrc && bundle exec puma`, but that seems to not work.

Comment: Exactly, you add the path and then you might need to reinitialise using `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I don't think puma will work if you don't have the ruby environment initiated in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean that `puma` shouldn't run? It does run, the app is live - it just doesn't connect to S3. (I haven't ignored your other suggestion I'm just away from my PC right now)

Comment: That's what I meant, it will not connect.

Comment: @AHT Where do you suggest putting that `source` command? I've tried plainly running it, and I've tried putting it in my `.bashrc`, but neither seem to work

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like if I export my environment variables in `.profile` then they are picked up by the server no problem. If I remove them from `.bashrc` then the server has no problems, but I can't get the variables in terminal. I guess they just do different things?